# Preferred way to handle UTC/local time in Qt's QDateTime?

Tags: qt, datetime, qdatetime

I have some code where I write a QDateTime to a file...

```
someQDateTime.toUTC().toString(Qt::ISODate)
```

and when I read it back using `QDateTime::fromString()`, I get the time interpreted as being in the system's time zone. I can manually append "Z" to the string when I write it out, or use `setTimeSpec()` after I read it, and then everything is fine, but is this the *preferred* way of doing this? Shouldn't toString() know to write out a Z when the timeSpec is UTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, at least according to ISO 8601 (section 4.2.4, [pdf here](http://dotat.at/tmp/ISO_8601-2004_E.pdf)), a `Z` is needed to differentiate between UTC and local time. Seems as if `QDateTime::toString()` doesn't follow this advice, while `QDateTime::fromString()` knows about it. ISO 8601 also contains this note in section 4.3.2 (where [T] is the time zone indicator, i.e. Z):

"By mutual agreement of the partners in information interchange, the character [T] may be omitted in
applications where there is no risk of confusing a date and time of day representation with others defined in this
International Standard."

You could always file a bug report (https://bugreports.qt.io/) to tell the Qt people about this small inconsistency and see what they have to say about it.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's a bug; looks like it's by design. Apparently they want to keep that information in `QDateTimePrivate`. I'll have to ask them why. :P

Comment: Something else to add - apparently .NET's `DateTime` doesn't print out a Z either for UTC times. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

[Qt bug 9698](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-9698) is about the behavior of `QDateTime::toString(Qt::ISODate)`. The omission of the time zone designator is reported there. Feel free to vote for the bug.

Comment: Fixed in 4.8.0, apparently.

Comment: Not fixed even in 4.8.5!